# Difference between CrossEntropyLoss and NNLLoss with log_softmax in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, classification, cross-entropy

When I am building a classifier in PyTorch, I have 2 options to do

1. Using the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` without any modification in the model
2. Using the `nn.NNLLoss` with `F.log_softmax` added as the last layer in the model

So there are two approaches.

Now, what approach should anyone use, and why?

Comment: What kind of model are you using?

Comment: A CNN based image classifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the same.

If you check [the implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#cross_entropy), you will find that it calls [`nll_loss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#nll-loss) after applying [`log_softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#log-softmax) on the incoming arguments.

```
return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
```

---

Edit: seems like the links are now broken, [here's the C++ implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e0ff6a21d8bf3935f4332fb18b40b48472f9b648/aten/src/ATen/native/LossNLL.cpp#L607-L612) which shows the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Both the cross-entropy and log-likelihood are two different interpretations of the same formula. In the log-likelihood case, we maximize the probability (actually likelihood) of the correct class which is the same as minimizing cross-entropy. Though you're correct both of these have created some ambiguity in the literature, however, there are some subtleties and caveats, I would highly suggest you go through this thread, as this topic has been rigorously discussed there. You may find it useful.

[Cross-Entropy or Log-Likelihood in Output layer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198038/cross-entropy-or-log-likelihood-in-output-layer)

Answer (score 0):

```
F.nll_loss(log(softmax(logits, dim=1)),targets)
```

equals

```
F.cross_entropy(logits,targets)
```